# JavaScript - How can I 'translate' the input to something different

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program where if you for example type in "less" in the textarea the output should show "<". What is the best way to do this?

This is how far I've gotten:

```
 <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Group 7 - Deckcode to JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Group 7 - Deckcode to JavaScript</h1>
    <p>Input your deckode below:</p>
    <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Translate</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input
        if (myTextarea == "less") {
        console.log("<");
    } 
    }
    </script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need a mapping table which will be referred everytime when a user enters a name.

Comment: how much words do you need to traslate here? is it a matter if all are visible at JS code? that can be a determinat to the solution

Comment: I would need to translate 20 words or less

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fish values out of the DOM incorrectly. Use `document.getElementById` to locate the element in the DOM, and take its `value` for the value you require.

```
function myFunction() {
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    if (textAreaValue == "less") {
      console.log("<");
    } 
}
```

Comment: `<!doctype html>
 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Group 7 - Deckcode to JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Group 7 - Deckcode to JavaScript</h1>
    <p>Input your deckode below:</p>
    <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Translate</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    if (textAreaValue == "less") {
      console.log("<");
    } 
}
    </script>
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @FrederikJorgensen Umm... yes it is. I just pasted the code from your comment (verbatim) into an HTML page and it works just fine. If you press the button and the term `less` is in the textarea, `<` is printed to the console. What exactly does "not working" mean here?

Comment: Uhh it's not displaying the > for me

Comment: Um. No, because it's displaying `<`!!! How are you verifying this? Where are you expecting to see the `<`? It's in the error console, right?

Comment: > is greater than :-)

Comment: I want it to show it below the textarea or just somewhere. I'm brand new to JavaScript but our first project was to make a translator in JavaScript.

Comment: I want it to be like Google Translate so when you enter the "less" in the box 1 it outputs "<" in box 2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an object like this:

```
var translations = {};
translations["less"] = "<";
translations["greater"] = ">";
```

And then in your function you do like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  console.log(translations[value] ? translations[value] : "No translation found");
}
```

It would also be easy to add more translations e.g. based on data from a database or similar.

Comment: Yes. It eliminates the need of huge if or switch statements and adding a new translations only requires adding it to the object. No actual coding is needed.

Answer (score 0):

as and alternative to IF-condition, you can use

```
if (textAreaValue.indexOf("less") > -1) {
    console.log("<");
}
```

so if the text area contains "less" text then the console prints "<"

[indexOf method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)